# Elixir script using Floki and HttPotion fails to parse url

Tags: url, enums, web-scraping, html-parsing, elixir

I'm trying to write a script using [Floki](https://github.com/philss/floki) and [HttPotion](https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion) to the text of articles from Wikipedia. My code up to the failure looks like this:

```
defmodule Scraper do

  def start do
    base = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
    response = HTTPotion.get base <> "/wiki/Main_Page"
    html = response.body
    main_bg = Floki.find(html, ".MainPageBG")
    main_bg
      |> Floki.find("table tr li a")
      |> Floki.attribute("href")
      |> Enum.map(fn(addr) -> HTTPotion.get(base <> addr) end)
  end
end
```

And I'm referencing something from the Floki readme:

```
html
|> Floki.find(".pages a")
|> Floki.attribute("href")
|> Enum.map(fn(url) -> HTTPoison.get!(url) end)
```

When I pipe my results to `Floki.attribute("href")` I get a nice list of url path names like:

```
["/wiki/Japanese_aircraft_carrier_Hiry%C5%ABwow",
 "/wiki/Boys_Don%27t_Cry_(film)wow", "/wiki/Elias_Abraham_Rosenbergwow",
 "/wiki/Japanese_aircraft_carrier_Hiry%C5%ABwow",
 "/wiki/Boys_Don%27t_Cry_(film)wow", "/wiki/Elias_Abraham_Rosenbergwow",
 "/wiki/Wikipedia:Today%27s_featured_article/November_2015wow",
 "https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/daily-article-lwow",
 "/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_articleswow", "/wiki/Schloss_Krobnitzwow",
 "/wiki/Prussiawow", "/wiki/Albrecht_von_Roonwow", "/wiki/Harry_Winerwow",
 "/wiki/Rob_Thomas_(writer)wow", "/wiki/Of_Vice_and_Menwow",
 "/wiki/Veronica_Marswow", "/wiki/Meithalunwow", "/wiki/Palestinian_peoplewow",
 "/wiki/Marj_Sanurwow", "/wiki/Soma_Norodomwow",...]
```

But, when the line `|> Enum.map(fn(addr) -> HTTPotion.get(base <> addr) end)` runs I get this error:

```
** (HTTPotion.HTTPError) {:url_parsing_failed, {:error, :invalid_uri}}
    (httpotion) lib/httpotion.ex:209: HTTPotion.handle_response/1
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:977: anonymous fn/3 in Enum.map/2
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1261: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:977: Enum.map/2
```

I see that `:url_parsing_failed`, but I don't understand why. When I try `Enum.map(fn(addr) -> HTTPotion.get(base <> addr)` with individual url paths from the list, they all work.

- Is my syntax wrong?
- Am I missing something about how pipes or Enums work?
- Am I on the right track?

Based on manukall's answer here is what worked:

```
defmodule Scraper do
  def transform_url(url_or_path = "/" <> _, base), do: base <> url_or_path
  def transform_url(url, _base), do: url

  def start do
    base = "https://en.wikipedia.org"
    response = HTTPotion.get base <> "/wiki/Main_Page"
    html = response.body
    main_bg = Floki.find(html, ".MainPageBG")
    main_bg
      |> Floki.find("table tr li a")
      |> Floki.attribute("href")
      |> Enum.map(fn(url) -> OldRazor.transform_url(url, base) end)
      |> Enum.map(fn(url) -> HTTPotion.get(url) end)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the list of urls again, you will notice one absoulte url in there: "https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/daily-article-lwow". This won't work with `HTTPotion.get(base <> addr)`, because it will end up requesting a url like "https://en.wikipedia.orghttps://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/daily-article-lwow".

One way to fix that could be writing another function `transform_url` that checks if the value starts with `/` and only then prepends the base url to it:

```
  def transform_url(url_or_path = "/" <> _, base), do: base <> url_or_path
  def transform_url(url, _base), do: url
```

You would then use that as

```
  ...
  |> Enum.map(fn(url) -> HTTPoison.get!(transform_url((url)) end)
```

Comment: I actually ran your code but put an `IO.inspect(url)` into the anonymous function right before the `HTTPotion.get!` part. So the last URL that was printed was the broken one.

Comment: With some tweaking that worked! Thanks. I don't really get what `(url_or_path = "/" <> _, base)` does though.

Comment: Great!
`url_or_path = "/" <> _` matches on binaries starting with `/` and then binds the whole binary to `url_or_path`, if it matched.
So basically the whole method does something like: 

if the first parameter start with "/", bind that parameter to `url_or_path`, prepend `base` and return that. otherwise just return the first parameter.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thanks again.